# Print every review stored in the database

Tags: php, mysql

I am in the process of building a institute review system and i just completed inserting reviews to the database. However i am in a fix as to how to display to the user all the reviews related to the particular institute.
Below is my code to retrieve review information along with the name of the person who has left the review:

```
$get_review_query = "SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE institute_id = {$id}";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $get_review_query);
if(!$result) {
    die("Database query failed.");
}                                                     
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count == 0) {
    $output = "There're no reviews for this institute.";
} else {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $review_contents = $row['content'];
        $institute_id = $row['institute_id'];
        $student_id = $row['student_id'];
        $date = $row['created_on'];

        $query_student_name = "SELECT f_name, l_name FROM students 
                               WHERE student_id = {$student_id}";
        $result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $query_student_name);
        if(!$result1) {
             die("Database query failed.");
        } else {
            $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
            $student_f_name = $row1['f_name'];
            $student_l_name = $row1['l_name'];
        }
    }
}
```

Now i want to display the reviews somewhere down the page:

```
<!-- display reviews -->
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Reviews for <?php echo $name; ?></legend>
          <br>
          <?php
          foreach($row as $value) {
              ?>
          <legend><?php echo $student_f_name . " ". $student_l_name; ?> said:</legend>
            <div id = "items" class="">
                <?php echo $review_contents; ?>
            </div>
          <br>
            <div>
                <?php echo $date; ?>
            </div>
          <?php } ?>
        </fieldset>
```

The above foreach loop doesn't work. It probably creates an infinite loop. I have tried using a for loop with $count as the maximum counter but that doesn't work either. Please suggest a for loop that prints all the reviews from the database.

Comment: The second loop is not working because after you've read all the results, `$row` is `NULL` and you've not saved the individual results to any array.  In your first loop, append the results to another array (or just output them on the fly) and display those results.

Comment: @drew010 still can't figure it out. Could you please give a detailed answer?

Comment: You have to retrieve and store data in array. in your `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))` loop write something like `$myData[]=$row` and then do foreach loop for `$myData`

Comment: You must use JOIN instead of running queries in a loop. Can you please post table structure for students and reviews.

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya tried this. The problem is, only one review is being displayed n number of times. (n being the number of reviews in the table)

Comment: then after this foreach print your array and see what it is returning print_r($myData[]);

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$get_review_query = "SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE institute_id = {$id}";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $get_review_query);
if(!$result) {
    die("Database query failed.");
}                                                     

    $reviews = array();
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($count == 0) {
        $output = "There're no reviews for this institute.";
    } else {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $query_student_name = "SELECT f_name, l_name FROM students 
                                   WHERE student_id = {$student_id}";
            $result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $query_student_name);
            if(!$result1) {
                 die("Database query failed.");
            } else {
                $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
                $row['f_name'] = $row1['f_name'];
                $row['l_name'] = $row1['l_name'];
            }

            $reviews[] = $row;
        }
    }

    if( $reviews ){
     ?>
       <fieldset>
            <legend>Reviews for <?php echo $name; ?></legend>
              <br>
              <?php
              foreach($reviews as $review) {
                  ?>
              <legend><?php echo $review['f_name'] . " ". $review['l_name']; ?> said:</legend>
                <div id = "items" class="">
                    <?php echo $review['content']; ?>
                </div>
              <br>
                <div>
                    <?php echo $review['created_on']; ?>
                </div>
              <?php } ?>
            </fieldset>
     <?php  
    }
```

Comment: tried this. The problem is, only one review is being displayed n number of times. (n being the number of reviews in the table)

Comment: How many reviews in table particular institute id above in your code ?

Comment: there are 3 reviews from 3 different users for one of the test cases. the output displays the latest review 3 times

Comment: what three times display review is duplicate ?

Comment: while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
print_r($row)
check this is different ?